# PHP: $this vs self

Tags: php

Есть такой код:

```
class main
{
    const MYCONST = "Hello world";

    public function printout()
    {
        echo $this::MYCONST, "\n";
        echo self::MYCONST;
    }
}
$obj = new main;
$obj->printout();
```

В чем разница между вызовами

```
$this::MYCONST;
self::MYCONST;
```

Comment: А вы знаете чем `$this`  от `self` отличаеться?

Comment: Больше пищи для [размышлений](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php): ``static::MYCONST`` ;)

Comment: $this - для объектов внутри класса
self - для использования в статическом контексте внутри класса

Comment: про static я знаю и позднее статическое связывание тоже, меня интересует не static

Answer (score 3):

Обратиться к `self::MYCONST` вы сможете из любого метода класса, из обычного и из статического. Обратиться к `$this::MYCONST` вы сможете только из объекта, т.е. в статическом методе класса такое обращение вызовет ошибку

```
class main
{
    const MYCONST = "Hello world";

    public static function printout()
    {
        echo $this::MYCONST, "\n";
    }
}
echo main::printout(); // Fatal error: Class name must be a valid object or a string i
```

Comment: ну если это единственное отличие, то жаль, т.к ничего особенного нет

Comment: @MaximPro особенности с self начинаются при наследовании, на уровне класса, да, ничего особенного.

Comment: да я знаю в таких случаях используют static =)

Comment: протестировал...выходит $this = static? так?